# Вывод изображений из Gallery

Tags: modx

Как мне сделать так, чтобы в вызове pdoPage выводились изображения из ОДНОГО альбома Gallery с разбивкой этих изображений на страницы? Я нашел как сделать вывод самих альбомов, но так и не нашел решения для непосредственно изображений. Что мне здесь стоит поменять и знать?:

```html
[[!pdoPage?
  &loadModels=`gallery`
  &class=`galAlbum`
  &select=`{"galAlbum":"*"}`
  &sortby=`id`
  &tpl=`@INLINE [[+name]]`
]]
```

Нужен ли &elements?

Куда установить название шаблона для одного изображения?

Нужен ли &parents?

UPD:

в связи с подсказкой частично получилось, вывод сделал теперь вот такой:

```
[[!pdoPage?
                          &parents          = `4`
                          &class            = `galItem`
                          &select           = `{"galItem":"*"}`
                          &sortby           = `id`
                          &ajaxMode         = `default`
                          &tpl              = `tpl_gallery_center`
                          &limit            = `8`
                        ]]
```

Но даже с указанием ресурса к которому привязана галерея, все равно выводятся вообще все изображения из всех существующих галерей

Вот как выглядит вывод изображений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У тегов img в атрибуте src пусто, хотя в alt и title прописаны названия изображений

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
[[!pdoPage?
    &select=>`{"galItem":"*"},
    &tpl=`gallery.row`
    &class=`galItem`
    &sortby=`id`
]]
```

Если альбом прикреплен к ресурсу, то нужно указывать `parents`

Comment: Появились элементы, спасибо, но появились вообще все изображения из всех существующих галерей) Добавил инфу в вопрос